# Post data to API in React Native only show empty

Tags: api, react-native, post

I am building an application in react native CRNA for the front-end side and using PHP for the backend side. But when I tried to post a data, for example login form, the result is only empty no matter what the given input is.

This is an example of my snippet code.

```
fetch('someURL', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: this.state.name,
                    email: this.state.email,
                    message: this.state.message,
                })
            })
            .then((response)=>response.json())
            .then((responseData)=>{
                Alert.alert(console.log(responseData))
                return responseData;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
}
```

I tried to check the value with console.log and didn't get anything (only empty).. What should I do? Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: The only way we can find out what exactly is the problem is if you post the code for the API endpoint you are trying to access.

Comment: you can install Reactotron plugin to see the real response from your API endpoint

Comment: I think the backend is fine, I tried to send something on postman and it's working fine. I havent tried with reactotron, will give any updates after I install it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first then() and put the response.json() into the next then(). In the same block as the Alert.

Comment: thanks for your response.. i tried to put `response.json()` on the second `then()` and remove the first one, but it's giving me an error said "can't find variable: response" but if I changed it to responseData.json, the console.log is still empty. also when I change it all to response, it's still empty..

Comment: Then I think is backend problem.. But to be sure check first the values this.state.name, this.state.email and this.state.message if they are correct before the fetch method.

Comment: I tried to post something directly to backend on postman and it's working perfectly fine. But if I do alert of {this.state.name} on the apps, it's showing the value. But I think it didn't pass to the api